# Static Constructor and Exceptions

Tags: c#, constructor

What happen if a static constructor throws and exception and it is not handled?

Will it remain till the application domain alive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An unhandled exception in a static constructor, will be wrapped in a `TypeInitializationException`. If you're on .NET 2 or newer an unhandled exception will terminate the process.

Answer (score 0):

The exception will propagate and if it is not caught somewhere like for example a global exception handler it will simply kill the application domain.

Answer (score 0):

if an Exception happens in a static Constructor and you don't catch it, then you will never use its static Method , filed or property, even cann't create its instance, otherwise it will cause a TypeInitializationException.