# How to solve "The issue with T?"/nullable constraint on type parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, nullable, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I'm designing an interface in C# 8.0 with `nullable` enabled, targeting .Net Standard 2.0 (using the [Nullable package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nullable/)) and 2.1. I am now facing *[The issue with `T?`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-out-nullable-reference-types/)*.

In my example, I am building an interface for a cache which stores `Stream`s/byte data, identified by a `string` key, i.e. the file system could by a trivial implementation. Every entry is additionally identified by a version, which should be generic. This version could for example be another `string` key (like an etag), an `int` or a `date`.

```
public interface ICache<TVersionIdentifier> where TVersionIdentifier : notnull
{
    // this method should return a nullable version of TVersionIdentifier, but this is not expressable due to 
    // "The issue with T?" https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-out-nullable-reference-types/
    Task<TVersionIdentifier> GetVersionAsync(string file, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);

    // TVersionIdentifier should be not nullable here, which is what we get with the given code
    Task<Stream> GetAsync(string file, TVersionIdentifier version, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);

    // ...
}
```

While I understand what the issue with `T?` is and why it is a non trivial problem for the compiler, I don't know how to handle this situation.

I thought of some options but neither of them seems to be optimal:

1. Disable `nullable` for the interface, manually tag non-nullable occurrences of `TVersionIdentifier`:

   ```
   #nullable disable
   public interface ICache<TVersionIdentifier>
   {
       Task<TVersionIdentifier> GetVersionAsync(string file, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
       // notice the DisallowNullAttribute
       Task<Stream> GetAsync(string file, [DisallowNull] TVersionIdentifier version, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
       // ..
   }
   #nullable restore
   ```

   This does not seem to help. When implementing `ICache<string>` in a nullable-enabled context, `Task<string?> GetVersionAsync` generates a warning as the signatures don't match. Most likely the compiler knows that the type given for `TVersionIdentifier` is non-nullable and enforces it's rules, even though `ICache` doesn't know about it. For popular interfaces like `IList<T>` this makes sense.

   This results in warnings so this does not seem to be a real option.
2. Disable nullable for the implementation of the member. While warnings are produced in either case it seems consequent to disable `nullable` for the interface then though (does this really make sense?).

   ```
   #nullable disable
       public Task<string> GetVersionAsync(string file, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
       {
           return Task.FromResult((string)null);
       }
   #nullable restore
   ```
3. Like (2) but  disable nullable for the whole implementing class (and the interface too). Maybe this is most consequent, as it clearly expresses *the concept of nullable reference types/generics/... does not work for this class* and the callers have to handle this situation as they had to earlier (pre C# 8.0).

   ```
   #nullable disable
   class FileSystemCache : ICache<string>
   {
       // ...
   }
   #nullable restore
   ```
4. Option (2) or (3) but suppressing the compiler warning instead of disabling nullable. Maybe the compiler draws wrong conclusions afterwards, so this is a bad idea?
5. Like (1) but with convention for implementers: Disable `nullable` for the interface, but annotate with `[DisallowNull]` and `[NotNull]` manually (see code in (1)). Use nullable types as `TVersionIdentifier` in all implementations manually (we can not enforce this). This might get us as close as we can get regarding correctly annotated assemblies. The consumers of our implemementation get warned when using nulls where they shouldn't and they get correctly annotated return values. This way is not very self-documenting though. Any possible implementer needs to read our docs to fully understand our intent. Thus, our interface isn't a good model for possible implementations, as it misses some aspects. People might not expect this.

Which way to go? Is there another way I missed? Are there any relevant aspects I missed?

I think it would have been great if Microsoft advised a possible workaround in the blog post.

Comment: You could rename your method `TryGetVersionAsync` and return a `Task<(bool hasVersion, TVersionIdentifier version)>`. That is, basically imitating `Nullable<T>` with a `ValueTuple`. C# 8's new `switch` expressions make it fairly easy to consume such results in a non-intrusive fashion, but then of course not every .NET Standard 2.0 consumer will have C# 8 yet. This does have the benefit of making the intent of the method very clear without having to rely on implicit nullability. The drawback is that implementers will have to write things like `(false, null!)` for references.

Comment: Apropos that: the "dammit" operator (`!`) (e.g. `Task.FromResult((string) null!)`) is usually a shorter and less invasive option that bothering with explicit `#nullable disable / restore` pairs. It was added to the language precisely because having to bend the rules for compatibility's sake and because the compiler can't know any better is fairly common (but I agree that putting `notnull` on the interface then is misleading to callers, so I wouldn't recommend going that way).

Comment: I have to admit I didn't decompile the results yet but I hoped the `#nullable disable` would result in a different annotated assembly too. I.e. a "nullability unknown" state instead of a "explicit not nullable but it's null though" state.
While I think your "sixth" `Try...` option is quite interesting, it doesn't feel like "the one way to go" too :/. I hoped there was a better option I've overlooked...

Comment: There is -- bite the bullet, drop backwards compatibility and change the compiler to support this scenario directly by generating more advanced code. ...but that's out of scope for you as a user of the language, of course. :-) Nullable reference types aren't perfect, they're explicitly designed as a stepping stone to get *some* validation done in spite of the existing situation. You've managed to hit on a particularly unfortunate scenario where they don't work very well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nullable reference types: How to specify "T?" type without constraining to class or struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55975211/nullable-reference-types-how-to-specify-t-type-without-constraining-to-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with C# 9, the interface could be declared like this:

```
public interface ICache<TVersionIdentifier> where TVersionIdentifier : notnull
{
    Task<Stream> GetAsync(string file, TVersionIdentifier version, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
    Task<TVersionIdentifier?> GetVersionAsync(string file, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
    // ...
}
```

It doesn't achieve what I try to achieve though.

An implementation of `ICache<string>` will correctly have the members:

```
public class StringVersionedCache : ICache<string>
{
    public Task<Stream> GetAsync(string file, string version, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public Task<string?> GetVersionAsync(string file, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

An implementation of `ICache<int>` will *incorrectly* have these members though:

```
public class IntVersionedCache : ICache<int>
{
    public Task<Stream> GetAsync(string file, int version, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // WRONG: needs to be Task<int?>
    public Task<int> GetVersionAsync(string file, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

@rikki-gibson mentioned [Nullable reference types: How to specify "T?" type without constraining to class or struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55975211/nullable-reference-types-how-to-specify-t-type-without-constraining-to-class) in the comments, thanks. It is realted and further helps understanding the issue, but doesn't solve the problem though (see above).

The imho cleanest solution I was able to come up with is described in [Returning nullable and null in single C# generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32315119/1200847).

Declare the interface this way:

```
public interface ICache<TVersionIdentifier> where TVersionIdentifier : notnull
{
    Task<Stream> GetAsync(string file, [DisallowNull] TVersionIdentifier version, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
    Task<bool> TryGetVersionAsync(string file, [NotNullWhen(true)] out TVersionIdentifier? result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
    // ...
}
```

Also note the `[NotNullWhen(true)]` attribute and [see the corresponding docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis#conditional-post-conditions-notnullwhen-maybenullwhen-and-notnullifnotnull). Thanks to C# 9 it is possible to have a nullable out parameter `out TVersionIdentifier? result`. If `TVersionIdentifier` is `int`, this will be `int` not `int?` (as described above). Given how `Try*` methods are typically used in .Net, the intention and semantics of the function are easily understandable though. Using the `NotNullWhen` attribute we get proper compiler null checks too. Thus, this solution meets my design goals.