# Nullability attributes on type parameter (C#)

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

From docs the main reason for `[AllowNull]` attribute is to apply it to generics, where `T?` syntax can't be used. But `AllowNull` is not allowed to be specified on generic parameters.

```
void f<[AllowNull] T>() {} // error
```

Is there any way to make function like this?

```
[return: NotNull]
T<TT> HasNoNulls<T, [NotNull] TT>(T<TT?>? val)
```

---

**UPDATE:** I get it why this is not allowed. Because null analysis is tied to data flow it only allowed on *variables*. How to solve this nested generic problem?

Comment: Can you give an example of `T<TT>`?

Comment: @Stefan This is not allowed syntax in c#. I used it to just show function signature. For example `T is List<> and TT is object --> T<TT> is List<object>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58569906/11683, which points to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-out-nullable-reference-types/#the-issue-with-t?

Comment: @GSerg more I think about this, more I understand, that this question is about limitation of generics int C#. There is now way to express functions that operate on types at compile time. Like `??? CretateWith<T, TT> ()` ; `List<int> a = CreateWith<List<>, int>()`

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing I get is

```
   [return: NotNullPost]
    public static T HasNoNulls<T, TT>([NotNullPost][AllowNull] T value)
        where T : IEnumerable<TT>
    {
        if (value.Any(e => e is null))
            throw new ArgumentException();
        return value;
    }
```

---

```
List<string?>? list = null;
// requires to specify types and use null assertion ↓
var ll = Check.HasNoNulls<List<string>, string>(list!, "");
ll[0].Trim(); // no warnings
```